# getting data from dynamically generated html form

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

I am dynamically generating a html page from data in the database(mainly labels retrieved since I'm in the stage of CREATING data to store in the db). I retrieve labels and id's from the database, then store it in a class which I return to jinja2 so that I can then dynamically generate all the labels and input boxes. Here is a snippet:

```
<div class="dataDiv">
            <label class="inputBoxLabels">Device<span style="padding-left: 85px;font-size: 12px;"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:6543/new_device/1">New</a></label>
            <select id="devices" class="inputBoxes" style="height: 25px;">
                {% for key, value in devices.iteritems() %}
                    {% if deviceID == key %}
                        <option value="{{ key }}" selected="selected">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
```

another example, this time an input box:

```
{% if inspection.statusDict|length > 0 %}
    <select class="inputBoxes" id="ins_' + {{ inspection.insID }} + '" style="height: 25px;">
        {% for key, value in inspection.statusDict.iteritems() %}
            <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% else %}
   <input type="text" class="inputBoxes" id="ins_' + {{ inspection.insID }} + '">
{% endif %}
```

This is what the `select` list looks like after is has been populated for visual reference:
[image]

Now the problem. I have everything inside a form and I have no idea how to retrieve the data from each input and select when I receive the post since it's all dynamically generated.

I originally thought of using jquery instead and ajax but if possible I'd like to stick to forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I *think* if you're submitting to a Pyramid view via POST you should be able to iterate over `request.POST` to get whatever was submitted.

Something like and inspect each `item`

```
for item in request.POST.keys():
  print item + ' - ' + request.POST[item]
```

I'd have to try it when I get home to a console to confirm.

Comment: thank you. I've never done form posts really and especially not in python. This was really helpful.